# Bat/cmd script - run multiple instances of a program, don't wait for each instance to finish

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to execute multiple instances of EXE simultaneously. However, the script is waiting for previous instance to finish before advancing to the next one. How to make it run all without waiting?

Comment: What is your current script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the START command. For example:

```
@echo off
start notepad
start notepad
start notepad
```